# Fullcalendar Scheduler Timeline View - Finding resource id of externally dragged event pre-drop

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I'm looking to find how to get the resource id of where an external event is being dragged over (pre-drop). The highlighting appears (fc-highlight-container class), but i'm looking to find the resource id of this highlighted area so that i can do some comparisons against the other events that are already placed within that resource before the event is actually dropped.

Once i know the resource id i can do the rest. I just have no idea where to start.

I'm currently using v3.10. I'm unable to upgrade to v4 due to a bug.

Also just using latest jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Alas, I seem to have found a solution.

For anyone else with a similar issue, the following use of the "eventAfterAllRender" hook seemed to have done the trick:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    $(".fc-rows>table>tbody>tr").droppable({
        tolerance: "pointer",
        over: function (event, ui) {
            var hoveredTR = $(this);
            console.log(hoveredTR.attr("data-resource-id"));
        }
    });
}
```